# Dynamic Programming - Two spies at the river

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I think this is a very complicated dynamic programming problem.

Two spies each have a secret number in [1..m]. To exchange numbers they agree to meet at the river and "innocently" take turns throwing stones: from a pile of n=26 identical stones, each spy in turn throws at least one stone in the river.

**The only information is in the number of stones each thrown in each turn. What is the largest m can be so they are sure they can complete the exchange?**

Develop a recursive formula to count. Here is the start of the table; complete it to n=26. (You should not expect a closed form.)

```
n 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

m 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 6 8 12 16 23
```

Here are some hints from our professor: I suggest changing the problem to making the following table: Let R(n,m) be the range of numbers [1..R(n,m)] that A can indicate to B if they start with n stones, and both know that A has to also receive a number in [1..m] from B.

For example, if A needs no more information, R(n,1) can be computed by considering how many stones A could throw (one to n), then B thows 1 (if any remain) and A gets to decide again. The base cases R(0,1) = R(1,1) = 1, and you can write a recursive rule if you are careful at the boundaries. (You should find the Fibonacci numbers for R(n,1).)

If A needs information, then B has to send it by his or her choices, so things are a little more complicated. Here is the start of the table:

```
n\ m  1     2     3     4     5

0     1     0     0     0     0

1     1     0     0     0     0

2     2     0     0     0     0

3     3     1     0     0     0

4     5     2     1     0     0

5     8     4     2     1     1

6    13     7     4     3     2

7    21    12     8     6     4

8    34    20    15    11     8

9    55    33    27    19    16
```

**From the R(n,m) table, how would you recover the entries of the earlier table (the table showing m as a function of n)?**

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. The secret number to be communicated to the other spy is the total number of stones thrown into the river?

Comment: @Codor From my understanding, the secret number is denoted by the sequence of throws. Consider the spy have 3 stones. He can : throw the three of them on the first turn (3-0-0), or one, then two (1-2-0) or (1-1-1) or (2-1-0). With three stones he can exchange a number from 1 to 4

Comment: Please enlarge on your example. Which choice would correspond to what number to comminucate?

Comment: @Codor, the "encoding" has not to be defined but you could map the sequences of throw with the numbers using a lexicographical order : (1-1-1) => 1, (1-2-0) => 2, (2-1-0) => 3, (3-0-0). It is just an example and our spies can chose whatever they want :)

Comment: @Rerito Throwing no stone at all doesn't allow the other mystery-monger to continue, which may be why m for n=3 is quoted 1 instead of 4.